# Store lines of code in variable/function without execution AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, function, variables

If i've got the following code for example:

```
s.x = 344 + Math.cos(s.Angle)*70;
s.y = 250 + Math.sin(s.Angle)*150;
s.Angle += td*.01;
```

I need it to be stored in a variable/function without execution as "s" and "td" are not yet in existence. I then need to be able to "insert" this code into the function where "s" and "td" are in existence by calling it from a single function/variable etc..

hope that makes sense,

thanks for any help

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can i tell flash not to execute the above code as s and td will not be in existence - so ill get an error... Is it possible to store it as a string and then tell flash to read it not as a string when i need it to? I've tried using `this[]` however that wont work beyond the semi-colon.

Comment: I would suggest what yclevine said and put it in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just want to put those lines of code into a function and then call the function with "s" and "td" as parameters.

Is there some reason that is not possible?

Comment: Yes that will work however it will be quite inconvenient and mean  I have to write a lot of extra code. Is it not possible to do something like the above mentioned? Otherwise ill just call function with s and td as parameters although i'd rather not if there's an alternative. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what extra code you would need to write. The purpose of a function is to do exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: It means I have to write an additional function with switch statement and 50 case statements, I would have liked to be able to just include it in my other function which already has the case statements (and in this function s and td cannot be the parameters).

Comment: Can you post a sample? I'm not sure I understand how your code is structured.

Comment: From what ive gathered what i really wanted to achieve doesnt seem possible, thanks anyway